# All http traffic to domain.com and all https to sub.domain.com with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have two domain names www.domain.com and sub.domain.com, and I want to redirect all the http traffic to www.domain.com and all the https traffic to sub.domain.com. For example, if the url called is http:// sub.domain.com/index.php, the server have to rewrite the url to http:// www.domain.com/index.php, and if the url called is https:// www.domain.com/index.php, the server have to rewrite the url to https:// sub.domain.com.

I have this code in htaccess but it does not work correctly:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/sub\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

It redirects correctly the https to sub.domain.com but only when there is no page indicated (https:// domain.com/index.php/some-page not work and https:// domain.com yes). For the http not work at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Make sure** both `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com` share the same document root folder. Otherwise, you will have to split htaccess code in two htaccess (one per root domain folder)

`/domain/root/folder/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`/subdomain/root/folder/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```